# Three grid, if one empty, expand two others

Tags: html, css

Im using a responsive three grid layout. Lets say each is 33% width, if one grid/div is empty, I'd like other two to expand to 50% width, and if 2 grid/divs are empty, I'd like remaining one to be 100% width.
Can it be done purely by CSS?

```
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 3
    </div>
</div>


/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.13%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 32.26%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `flex`. Here is how simple it is achieve this by CSS-

```
.section {
    display: flex;
}
.section .col {
    flex-grow: 100;
}
.section .col:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to see this in action - https://jsfiddle.net/schikara/oeb235gu/6/

Also, to know more about Flex here is the link - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Im afraid it only works if div is completely removed, not empty?

Comment: mind that `:empty` works if there is no white-space at all, it means that `<div class="col span_1_of_3"></div>`or `<div class="col span_1_of_3"><!-- comment --></div>` are `:empty`  but `<div class="col span_1_of_3"> </div>`is not  :(  `flex:1;` is plenty enough btw ;)